# Dart reference to map not changing map

Tags: dart

I am wondering why map1 fails to print `{a: 2, b: 3}` like map2 does.

```
void main() {
  Map<String, int> myMap1 = {"a": 1, "b": 2};
  Map<String, int> myMap2 = {"a": 1, "b": 2};

  print("before: $myMap1 , $myMap2"); // before: {a: 1, b: 2} , {a: 1, b: 2}


  upgradeAndSetEqual(myMap1);
  myMap2 = upgradeAndReturn(myMap2);

  print(" after: $myMap1 , $myMap2"); //  after: {a: 1, b: 2} , {a: 2, b: 3}


}

void upgradeAndSetEqual(Map<String, int> toUpgrade) {
  toUpgrade = toUpgrade.map((key, val) {
    val += 1;

    return new MapEntry(key, val);
  });
}

Map<String, int> upgradeAndReturn(Map<String, int> toUpgrade) {
  return toUpgrade.map((key, val) {
    val += 1;

    return new MapEntry(key, val);
  });
}
```

I have tried to find if Dart is pass-by-reference or pass-by-value and found this.
https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/iP5TiJMW1F8/discussion

But, I don't understand why it doesn't seem to be working for the previous example.

Here is the code in a DartPad
https://dartpad.dartlang.org/452f15102a2c52d10ce28ff9ebe445b2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.map(...)` creates a new map, it isn't modifying the map that it is called on

```
void upgradeAndSetEqual(Map<String, int> toUpgrade) {
  toUpgrade = toUpgrade.map((key, val) {
    val += 1;

    return new MapEntry(key, val);
  });
}
```

`toUpgrade = ...` has no effect, because it is a parameter and changing what it references doesn't change other references.

If you pass a map (or any object) as parameter, the reference (pointer) is passed by value. The copy still references the same value instance the caller passed though.
This means updating what `toUpgrade` points to, doesn't change the reference on the caller site.

Answer (score 2):

It's best to think of Dart as "pass by value", but with a very shallow copy.  Altering an incoming parameter does nothing.  But calling methods on the parameter that mutate the underlying object in-place can definitely alter the original value.